# Where can I find API for companies in Sweden?

Tags: api, companies

Do you guys know where I can find data of companies in Sweden?
Preferable an API.

In Denmark they have an API, that lets you get details of all registered companies (such as name, address, phone etc.): www.cvrapi.dk

- Data: Company details, just as Name, Address, City, Phone number etc.
- Context: User input company registration number. Website then extract
  as many details of the company as possible, from an API.
- Region: Sweden, Europe.
- License: Public available.
- Format: Restful API, json.
- Authority: Government-issued data.
- Requirements: Input has to be company registration number.

Comment: Hmm... i think this might have been posted in the wrong group.

In Denmark they have an API, that let you get details of all danish companies: www.cvrapi.dk. Is looking for a similar tool, for companies in Sweden.

Comment: Should be correct now.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCorporates](https://opencorporates.com/) is a global database of companies. They provide an [API](https://api.opencorporates.com/documentation/API-Reference).
For instance, this query lists the 1,345,795 Swedish companies that they know of:

https://api.opencorporates.com/companies/search?jurisdiction_code=se

Comment: Good starting point, but very limited information. The majority of the data is just company name / registration number. Not much you can do with this

Answer (score 1):

If you search Rapid API for "Sweden Company Data", you should find some resources, here is an example: https://rapidapi.com/appaio/api/sweden-company-data/